# react-responsive-carousel control-dots in vertical position

Tags: css, reactjs

By default control dots on carousel are placed horizontally at the bottom of carousel, even if we set vertical swipe property. Is there a way to place control dots vertically (preferably RHS of image). Please refer attached image.

[image]

Thanks

Comment: According to the docs on their github page you can pass an axis prop which accepts either vertical or horizontal

Comment: Read the package documents if they allow that functionality u can do that way else u will change the package customization and do that thing.

Comment: @SakoBu, axis prop controls the swipe direction only. It has no effect on control dots position..

Answer (score 0):

Maybe try to implement custom styling to the **.control-dots element**

Something like:

.control-dots{
   display: inline-block;
   width: 50px; // To reduce available space, so that the dots have to stack on        each other
}

To customise the dots themselves you can refer to **.control-dots .dot element**

Comment: Sorry first time commenting.

Answer (score 0):

You can use axis prop. `<Carousel axis="vertical" />`